How to run through a loop through json and find the relevant index of the value by mapping it with another array using vue js typescript?
logkeys has value
['client', 'manager', 'server', 'public', 'network']

checkedData has value
{
  0: 'infoclient', 
  1: 'warnmanager', 
  2: 'errorserver', 
  3: 'warnpublic', 
  4: 'errornetwork'
}

masks has value
['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc']

I want to run a loop through checkedData and find the relevant index of the value by mapping it with masks.
For eg: infomqttclient has 'info' in it which is one of the entries in mask. So, I want to return 0, which is the index of 'info' inside mask
Here's the code
const checkedData = ref([])
const masks = ref(['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc'])
const applyChanges = () => {
  // logkeys has value ['client', 'manager', 'server', 'public', 'network']. 
  checkedData has value {
    0: 'infomqttclient',
    1: 'warnconfigmanager',
    2: 'errorwebserver',
    3: 'warnpubsusb',
    4: 'errornetwork'
  }

  let logKeys = Object.keys(logData.value)

  for (var k = 5, i = 0; i < 5; i++, k--) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (checkedData.value[i].includes(tracelogKeys[i])) {
        // const index = tracelogKeys.map((e) => e).indexOf(tracelogKeys[i])
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm struggling with the mapping part and if this code could be more optimised. I'm also facing some typescript warnings. How do I do the mapping in the optimal way?

You can achieve what you need by looping over the values of the checkedData object, then checking the value against the mask array entities to find the index of values which have the same starting string value:
Object.values(checkedData).map(c => masks.findIndex(m => c.startsWith(m)));

That will build an array of the matching mask indexes which you can work with as required.
Here's a full working example:


const checkedData = {
  0: 'infomqttclient',
  1: 'warnconfigmanager',
  2: 'errorwebserver',
  3: 'warnpubsusb',
  4: 'errornetwork',
  5: 'foobar' // no match = -1
};
const masks = ['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc'];

const indexes = Object.values(checkedData).map(c => masks.findIndex(m => c.startsWith(m)));
console.log(indexes);



Note: this can be made simpler if you convert checkedData in to an array instead of an object, which I'd argue it should be already. Secondly, you can convert this to a loop instead if you'd prefer to process each value in the iteration:


const checkedData = {
  0: 'infomqttclient',
  1: 'warnconfigmanager',
  2: 'errorwebserver',
  3: 'warnpubsusb',
  4: 'errornetwork',
  5: 'foobar' // no match = -1
};
const masks = ['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc'];

Object.values(checkedData).forEach(c => {
  const index = masks.findIndex(m => c.startsWith(m))
  
  console.log(index); // do something with the index here...
});



